# VB Compile Error - "New cannot be used in interface"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm very new to Visual Basic and the following problem has me confused. The code shown below work fine as long as I don't import Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word . Once I do import that, I'm getting a compile time error on the panAdd.Location statement saying that 'new' cannot be used on an interface. This error shows up in a number of spots in the application. I would appreciate it if someone could describe why I'm getting this error now and what fix I could use to get around it. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

```
    Public Sub MoveAdd(entries As Integer)
    Dim addpos As Integer = 0
    addpos = 80 + (entries * 30)
    panAdd.Location = New Point(0, addpos)
    panAdd.Size = New Size(800, 100)
End Sub
```

Comment: fix worked. Thx. Getting same error for: Dim cbAdd  = New Checkbox

Comment: Try prefix the Checkbox Class with System.Windows.Forms

Comment: P.S. If you google vb.net and the class name in question, you will usually find a result from msdn that will tell you what namespace the class belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is getting confused between 'System.Drawing.Point' class and the 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Point' interface.

Try changing the line to this

```
panAdd.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, addpos)
```

Comment: Thanks Spock - logic prevails. Your suggestion worked for all the New Point problems but left me with one. I'm getting the same error for the following line. I tried looking through the System reference but couldn't find anything. I'd appreciate your help.